# Using fork in unix

Tags: unix

I am trying to learn forks and came across `&&` between two fork(). How does `&&` and `||` work when using `fork()` command. For example, if I have something like below-

```
fork();
fork() && fork() || fork(); 
fork() && fork();
```

THe number of processes spawned after execution of these lines is 29 or 30. How can one get to this conclusion?

Comment: `fork` returns 0 to the child.

Comment: Yes I know it returns 0 to the child and the child process id to itself.Ok so they are normal logical operators . But then why is no of processes at the end coming out to be 29 or 30

Comment: It's not *29 or 30*. 29 are spawned. 30 is the total count of processes. The original process counts as one, the other 29 are spawned during execution. See my answer for further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's step aside for a moment and think about the behavior of the `&&` and `||` operators. There is nothing special about using `fork(2)` with these (although it is unnecessarily confusing and should be done only for educational purposes).

Recall that these are short-circuit operators, that is, only the necessary operands are evaluated. In `a || b`, `a` is first evaluated; if it has a true value, `b` is not evaluated because the outcome of the `||` is already known, otherwise, `b` is evaluated. Similarly, with `a && b`, `a` is evaluated first; if it has a false value, `b` is not evaluated, otherwise, `b` is evaluated to determine the outcome.

With that in mind, let's step through the code to count the number of processes. The rest of this answer assumes that `fork(2)` is always successful.

**First line**

```
fork();
```

After this line, we have spawned a total of 1 process, and there are 2 active processes running.

**Second line**

```
fork() && fork() || fork();
```

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so this is equivalent to:

```
(fork() && fork()) || fork();
```

So, we've got 2 processes executing this. The first `fork()` is evaluated and a new process is created. It returns 0 on the new process, so the second `fork()` in that process will not be evaluated. Remember that this happens twice (we had 2 processes) - we now have 4 processes. In two of them, the first `fork(2)` returned 0, so the second `fork()` is not executed, however, the third `fork(2)` will because of the `||` semantics. In the other two, `fork()` returned non-zero, so the second `fork()` will be evaluated because it's part of `&&`.

So the first two call the last `fork()` (the one on the right of `||`), forking again, adding 2 new processes to the process pool. We now have 6 processes. The other 2 are on the second `fork()`: again, 2 new processes are created, raising the process count to 8.

Now the situation is similar: the parents of these 2 new processes see `fork()` return non-zero, so they do not call the 3rd `fork()` because the result of the `||` is known by now. The 2 children see `fork()` return 0, so they go on to evaluate the 3rd and last `fork()` on that line, creating 2 more processes: we now have 10 processes.

**Third line**

```
fork() && fork();
```

Alright, we have 10 processes that are going to execute this line. The semantics are the same: each of the 10 processes executes the first `fork()`, bringing the process count to 20. Out of the 20 processes, 10 of them (all of the children of the first `fork()` in that line) will see `fork(2)` return 0, so they won't move to the 2nd `fork()`. The other 10 - the parents - will see `fork()` return non-zero, so they will call the 2nd `fork()` to determine the final outcome of the `&&`. Together, they all create 10 more processes, raising the total number of processes to 30.

**Summary**

In the end, we have 30 running processes (a total of 29 were spawned). You can confirm this by printing in the end and counting the number of lines in the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    fork();
    fork() && fork() || fork(); 
    fork() && fork();
    printf("PID = %ld\n", (long) getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

Example running:

```
$ ./a.out | wc -l
      30
```